# In C++, what happens if two different functions declare the same static variable?

Tags: c++, function, static, static-variables

```
void foo() {
    static int x;
}

void bar() {
    static int x;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

Comment: They don't declare the same variable. Two different functions can never declare the same static local variable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They each see only their own one.  A variable cannot be "seen" from outside the [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)) that it's declared in.

If, on the other hand, you did this:

```
static int x;

void foo() {
    static int x;
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

then `foo()` only sees its local `x`; the global `x` has been "hidden" by it.  But changes to one don't affect the value of the other.

Comment: are anonymous namespaces considered better style than static globals in C++? The two uses of "static int x;" (one global, one local) seems to complicate the question.

Comment: @awoodlannd: the use of `static` for this purpose is deprecated in C++ (D.2/1). Whether it's better style depends whether the person you ask agrees with that deprecation...

Comment: @steve Wow, didn't realise that was actually deprecated, I'd come across quite a few (sensible) style guides that strongly discouraged it though.

Comment: @awoodland: don't be over-awed, deprecation in the C++ standard really doesn't mean much. It's defined as "not guaranteed to be part of the Standard in future revisions". But *non-deprecated* features aren't guaranteed to be part of the Standard in future revisions, either, for example exported templates are straight removed from C++0x. 7.3.1.1/2 does specifically say that unnamed namespaces are superior, though.

Answer (score 6):

The variables are distinct, each function has it's own scope.  So although both variables last for the lifetime of the process, they do not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly fine. In practice the actual name of the variable in the output of the compiler can be thought of as something like `function_bar_x`, i.e. it is the responsibility of your compiler to ensure that these do not clash.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happen, both variables have theri scope and mantain their values to call in call

Answer (score 1):

The two static vars are different.

Answer (score 0):

The compilator translates each variable in a unique manner, such as `foo_x` and `bar_x` in your example, so they are threated differently.

Don't do this as your code will be hard to read and maintain after some time since you will not able to catch at once of what `x` are you referring to.